# Chamar valor de outra página

Tags: php, array, select, variáveis

Olá, pessoal. Estou tendo um probleminha com a passagem de dado de uma página para outra. Já tentei por session e não muito certo e vou explicar o motivo:

Tenho uma página de notícia que as distribuem por um for em $arr[] onde encaixo o título, corpo da notícia etc. Aí, ao entrar numa notícia específica (aquele leia mais), tenho que dar um SELECT no banco de dados novamente e distribuir o título, corpo etc da notícia e isso eu faço pelo ID dela no banco de dados. Acontece que pra passar o ID da notícia que ele clicou pro SELECT da outra página eu me confundo todo.
Nas minhas tentativas ficou algo do gênero:

***1º*** **salvando o dado na variável:**
$variavel = array("$arr[2]")

***2º*** **pegando essa dado pela sessão:**
SELECT bla bla bla WHERE id = $variavel e ele não retorna o valor dessa variável
*fiz mais ou menos acima, é claro que abri as sessões e tudo mais kkkkkk*

Enfim, obrigado desde já!

Comment: Amigo nao tem como determinar a falha assim, por favor leia o link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Coloca o código da segunda página e o link ou como vc passa a variavel da primeira para a segunda.

Comment: Quando usas `$variavel = array("$arr[2]");` será que queres usar `$variavel = $_POST("$arr[2]");`? Repara que são coisas diferentes.

Comment: boas se queres guardar isso numa variavel de sessão tens de iniciar a sessão. se queres enviar isso para outra pagina onde fazes o pedido tens de ter um return da variavel. eu uso ajax para fazer pedidos ao servidor

Comment: Me dá um retorno depois se deu certo ok? Boa sorte ai!

Comment: @AllanAndrade fiz o seguinte: criei uma sessão e passei o valor do array. Mas, ao tentar resgatar esse valor em outra página, ele só mostra o ID de valor 1. O que não entendi é que ao dar um echo na página que passei o array, ele mostra o ID da notícia perfeitamente em cada repetição for. O problema está na página onde "resgato" esse valor. Será que consegui explicar com clareza esse meu problema?

Comment: Posta o código que você fez que dou uma olhada.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não consegui entender muito bem sua duvida, mas vou tentar lhe ajudar.

Se oque você quis dizer é o seguinte: "Você tem um site de noticias e quer pegar o ID da notícia quando o visitante clicar em 'Leia mais...'.

Se for isto mesmo, o procedimento correto para que você pegue o ID seria o seguinte. Para carregar as noticias você utiliza o método `$_GET` para carregar o conteúdo da notícia.

Assim o site ficará assim:
Quando o visitante clicar em "Leia mais..." ele será redirecionado para uma pagina com o línk 'site.com/?noticia=3'(Noticia=3, é um exemplo de `$_GET['noticia']`, isso fica a seu dispor.

Espero que tenha resolvido sua dúvida.

Comment: Eu estou tentando passar por sessão. Acontece que dentro da repetição for ao dar um echo no $_SESSION[id]= $arr[2], ele mostra o ID perfeitamente. Porém quando vou resgatar esse valor em outra página ele só mostra o valor 1.

Answer (score 1):

Tentando ser didático, acho que você poderia tentar da seguinte forma... (não sei qual o banco de dados usa, fiz um exemplo usando MYSQL).

Na página que lista as notícias, no link "leia mais" de cada notícia faça assim:

```
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($rs_noticias); $i++){    
     echo '<div>';
     echo '<h2>' . mysql_result($rs_noticias, $i, 'titulo_noticia') . '</h2>';
     echo mysql_result($rs_noticias, $i, 'texto_noticia');
     echo '<a href="leia_mais.php?id_noticia=' . mysql_result($rs_noticias, $i, 'codigo_noticia') . '">Leia mais...</a>';
     echo '</div>';
}
```

Na página que irá detalhar a notícia, que no exemplo se chama 'leia_mais.php', você poderá fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
$codigo_noticia = $_GET['id_noticia'];
$sql = 'SELECT bla bla bla WHERE id =' . $codigo_noticia;
echo $sql;
```

Espero ter ajudado! Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar!

Comment: Vale lembrar que as funções mysql_* estão obsoletas. É recomendável utilizar mysqli ou PDO.